Is there a way to make an image display the top of the image instead of zooming in on the center of the img?
I want to display the top of the image with the bottom part of the image hidden. The overflow is hidden but instead of displaying the image from top down, the image is being cut through the middle with a small part of both the top and the bottom hidden. Is there a way to fix this with css or do I need to crop the image manually?
Here is my code relative to the image..
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
}

I have tried different position types. I'm very new to making websites and can't think of other things to try to try to fix the problem

I don't think CSS support that, but you could place the full size image inside a smaller div with overflow: hidden to achieve this.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Certainly not while using object-fit: since the whole point is to make the image fit the container, not exceed it. Frankly, I'd be using a background image and then you can scale and position it any way you want. Alternatively, a transform and/or transform-origin might be another option.

object-position is what you look for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position

We. need a bit more detail about the context. width is 100% of what, what if the aspect ratios are reversed, is the image still to be 100% wide?

Here is a way using a couple of div containers with overflow-y:hidden; and overflow-y:scroll; as well as object-position: to show you how to achieve this.
The div with the red border shows you how to show only the top part of the image. The div with the green border shows you the image scrolling so that you can verify for yourself which part of the image is actually being shown in the red div.
To adjust which part of the image is being shown, you need to change the value of:
object-position: 0px 0px;
to something like:
object-position: 0px -200px;
For more information, please refer to: object-position on MDN


.fixed-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 3px red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scrolling-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 3px green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
}

.offset-image {
  object-position: 0px 0px;
}
<div class="fixed-container">
  <img class="offset-image" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/500/500">
</div>
<br/>
<div class="scrolling-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/500/500">
</div>




Yes, you can do this with object-position: top.
This snippet below demonstrates how it works. The first image is constrained only in its width, so the entire image is displayed in its intrinsic aspect ratio (square). The second image has a height constraint added, as well as object-fit: cover to specify automatic cropping. Note that the central part of the image is retained by default: the top and bottom edges are cropped. The third image has object-position: top added to specify that we want the automatic croping to retain the top of our image.



body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.i2, .i3 {
  height: 120px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.i3 {
  object-position: top;
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/480">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/480" class="i2">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/480" class="i3">



